# React setState hook's previous param object gives inconsistent values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, setstate

I'm using a `useEffect` hook to trigger a setState update. I'm getting some strange and inconsistent behaviour from the *previous* param:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentPicturesObject((existing) => {
            const clone = {...existing}
            console.log({
                existing,
                existingdotNocolor: existing.nocolor,
                selectedColorState,
                selectedColorArray: existing["nocolor"],
                clone
            });
            return existing
        });
    }, [selectedColorState]);
```

So you'd expect that the clone of the object would return an object with the same keys and values, right? Not here:

[image: screenshot of console log]

Somehow `existing` goes from being an object with a `nocolor` prop with an array of two strings, to switching to an array with one string. Similarly when I try to access the `nocolor` prop it only returns an array with one string.

I can't understand. `existing` changes as soon as I try to access it with anything other than simply console logging it directly?

Comment: Inside the callback function of `setCurrentPicturesObject`, did you mean to return `clone` instead of `existing`?

Comment: No - the return value isn't important. I just put anything in there to show a working function. The problem is whatever I try to do to update the ```existing``` state, it reverts to a different/wrong state. I'm trying to understand why so I can avoid/fix the issue.

Comment: How the existing state has been defined?

Comment: Can you create a minimal demo that produces your problem? Currently you just return the existing state. Code you have shared isn't helping in identifying the cause of your problem.

Comment: @hade and Yousaf, it's rather complicated. I don't suppose anyone knows, in general terms, what might be the cause of a parameter giving simultaneous, inconsistent values?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure on the details, but essentially it seems that the console is logging a live view of the object, which is a static string. More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278281/11664580).